# Python JWT decode - specify multiple secrets paired with algorithms list?

Tags: python, encryption, jwt

Python JWT allows to try decoding with multiple algorithms:

`jwt.decode(encoded, 'secret', algorithms=['HS512', 'HS256'])`

Is there any way to use this list of algorithms paired with a list of secrets? In my use case there are some fallback algorithms, but they each use different keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a try catch logic to fallback, something like::

```
def jwt_decode(encoded, pairs):
    for alg, secret in pairs:
        try:
            return jwt.decode(encoded, secret, alg)
        except jwt.SomeError:
            pass

    raise jwt.SomeError
```

Those `SomeError` should be replaced with a correct error.

Then use this `jwt_decode` function to fallback:

```
jwt_decode(encoded, [('HS512', 'secret-1'), ('HS256', 'secret-2')])
```